# In wso2 esb how to call websokcet published by api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have published a websocket api as given in the [Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Create+a+WebSocket+API), So I wanted to call that websocket API through wso2 ESB. So, how to pass the Auth header as I'm getting the following error on the console.

```
[2018-10-02 18:24:36,503] ERROR - InboundWebsocketSourceHandler Endpoint not found for port : 9099 tenant domain : null
```

Below is the ESB to call websocket API:

```
<api context="/test" name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="message" value="********************************************input**********************"/>
            </log>
            <property name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Bearer cf920eb2-960c-383c-b556-78e9258fd8d3"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <http method="post" uri-template="ws://localhost:9099/echowebsocket/1.0"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
         </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

outflow sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="outflowDispatchSeq" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="message" value="************************************************"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Comment: is your web socket API is created and published in super tenant domain or in a tenant domain?

Comment: if it is created and published in a tenant domain other than the super tenant, your URL needs to be changed by appending the '/t/tenantdomain' after the 9099 port. For example if your tenant is abc.com, then the uri-template will be ws://172.17.0.1:9099/t/abc.com/websocket/1.0.

Comment: Yeah that I know but I have created and published API as supertenant. So, no '/t/tenantdomain' required. And the URL is correct only as I have tested using netty client they provided, in that one it is working. This exception I'm getting may be because of Authentication.